# Fluxbox shuts my screens off after some idle moment

Tags: screensaver, fluxbox

I have fluxbox installed beside unity, my distro being ubuntu 13.04.

Under unity I have configured my computer not to suspend, not to lock, and not to shut off screens after some idle moment. This works ok.

However, I am using fluxbox 99% of the time, and under fluxbox, my screens shut off after something like 10 or 15 minutes. It's not a screensaver, my screens go into pause.

I don't know the application that manage this, and how to configure it so as my screens won't shut off.

This is a problem for me because when waking up, only the second screen will be restored,  even if I run arandr scripts again and again, trying to get my main screen back.

My main screen only comes back if I close then reopen my laptop. Maybe that's the issue I should worry about, but I have not the single idea which application manage that either.

Any idea what's going on and where I should look at ?

**Note**: I've found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/disable-screensaver-in-fluxbox-868131/) a suggestion for modifying `~/.xinitrc` and adding `xset -dpms s off`. However I don't have such file in my ~ directory. I have found a file with a similar name /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc. Should I modify this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `xset -dpms s off` to the file `~/.fluxbox/startup` seems to do the trick very well.